# How to add lag to the predecessor field in MS Project using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to add a time lag to a predecessor field in MS Project and I am having difficulty when a lag already exists against that predecessor.

For example, when its just a predecessor I just use:

```
T.Predecessors + "FS +" & Time_lag & " hrs"
```

However if there is already a time lag i am struggling to work out how to add say another 2 hr lag when there is already a 3 hr lag associated with that task.

I am sure there is a better way than using my text-based approach to adding the lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to remember that the Predecessor field shows the collection of [Task Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.taskdependencies) strung together (comma-separated). What you want to do is update that particular dependency, and not the whole collection. The [Task Dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.taskdependency) object has several properties including [Lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.taskdependency.lag).

In your scenario, you have a task with a single dependency and you want to add 2 hours to the lag, where `t` is your task and lag is represented in minutes:

```
t.TaskDependencies(1).Lag = t.TaskDependencies(1).Lag + 60 * 2
```

In more complicated scenarios the task will have multiple dependencies and you need to find the correct one. In this case, we set a lag of 2 days for the link to the predecessor task with the UniqueID of 2:

```
Dim td As TaskDependency
For Each td In t.TaskDependencies
    If td.From.UniqueID = 2 Then
        td.Lag = 60 * 8 * 2
    End If
Next td
```